# Printing with no brackets in haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I am having troubles printing chars with no brackets. (Not '%' , but only %)
I've tried creating newtype for my printing and still can't get around the brackets.
Any tips?

Comment: You can try `putChar`?

Comment: We can't tell you what's wrong with your code if you don't show us it – please edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Overwhelmingly likely answer: use `putChar` (or, for longer outputs, its big brothers `putStr` and `putStrLn`) instead of `print`.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply define

```
showNoQuotes :: Show a => a -> [Char]
showNoQuotes x = [c | c <- show x, c /= '\'']
```

Try it:

```
> putStrLn $ showNoQuotes '%'
%
```